# Why is my JS code going on, while the DOM manipulation isn't finished

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Building a small file uploader, I use a something like the following snippet. It should print me a list of the selected files, before starting the upload (here an alert) right away. In firefox everything works as expected. But in Chrome the alert is fired before the list is printed.

Why is this so? How can I force JS to wait until the list there? What is best practice here?

```js
document.querySelector("#inputFiles").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var files = this.files;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < files.length) {
    document.querySelector("#filelist").innerHTML += files[i].name + "<br>";
    i++;
  }
  alert("start upload, after list is printed!");
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFiles" multiple/>
<div id="filelist"></div>
```

Comment: put `alert("start upload, after list is printed!");` where `false` is

Answer (score 0):

1.ecause page rendering is DOM operation, would be Javascript engine in the event queue ;
2.lert ( ) is a built-in function of the window, is considered to be synchronized CPU code ;
3.javascript engine will give priority to perform the synchronization code, alert popup shows up first ;
4.lert a special block of nature, the implementation of the javascript engine block live;

rom the above reasons, led to the bizarre " alert execution order problem ". We are unable to render a page into a sync operation, then had to alert ( ) to become asynchronous Code, which you can perform after rendering the page.